# question about binary search tree-insert value to binary search tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a question about my homework, I need to insert value to the tree but is not insert correctly.

**This my question:** Complete the following method which inserts a new node containing the value data into the binary search tree pointed to by the parameter treePtr. It should insert the data so that the resulting tree is still a binary search tree and return a pointer to the root node. Note that the tree might be empty to start with (that is, the value of the parameter treePtr might be null).

**This is my code:**

```
public static TreeNode insertValue(TreeNode treePtr, int data) {

if (treePtr == null) {
            return new TreeNode(data, null, null);
        }

        if (treePtr != null) {
           new TreeNode(treePtr.data, null, null);
        }

        if (treePtr.data> data) {
            return insertValue(new TreeNode(data, null,treePtr ), data);
        }
        if (treePtr.data < data) {
                      return insertValue(new TreeNode(data, treePtr ,null), data);

}
        return treePtr;
```

**This is the answer that I received:**

```
The tree for example:
   (- 632 (- 725 -))
After inserting 725, the tree should be:
   (- 632 (- 725 -))
Your solution produced this:
   ((- 632 -) 725 -)
```

I need help with this question.

Thank you, everyone.

Comment: Can you please share your full code? need to check what are doing inside your insertValue method.

Comment: sure, sorry i probably didn't notice

Comment: I add the method for the body question thank you